# Why doesn't my code print the password when it has all the required premises?

Tags: python-3.x, passwords

```
`f=0
import random
chars_lower= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
chars_upper= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numbers= "0123456789"
symbols= "¡!¿?<>$#@%&€*+-"
password_length= 8
chars= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789¡!¿?<>$#@%&€*+-"
while f==0:
    password_random= "".join(random.sample(chars, password_length))
    e= 0
    for i in chars_lower:
        for j in chars_upper:
            for n in numbers:
                for k in symbols:
                    if i in password_random and j in password_random and k in password_random and n in password_random:
                        e=1
                        f=1
if e==1:
    print(password_random)`
```

creating an automatic password in case the user doesn't write his password correctly after 3 tries

```
t=0
list_lower=[]
list_upper=[]
list_numbers=[]
list_symbols=[]
for i in chars_lower:
    list_lower.append(i)
for j in chars_upper:
    list_upper.append(j)
for n in numbers:
    list_numbers.append(n)
for k in symbols:
    list_symbols.append(k)
for i in range(3):
    name= input("Write a name that contains 8 characters and hit ENTER: ")
    password= input("Write a password that contains 8 characters and hit ENTER: ")
    if len(name)==8 and len(password)==8: 
        for i in password:
            if i in list_lower:
                for j in password:
                    if j in list_upper:
                        for n in password:
                            if n in list_numbers:
                                for k in password:
                                    if k in list_symbols:
                                        t=1
                                    else:
                                        t=2
                            else:
                                t=2
                    else:
                        t=2
            else:
                t=2
    else:
        t=2
    if t==1:
        break

if t==1:
    print("Your user name is",name,"and your password is",password)
elif t==2:
    print("You have already used all your chances to write your password, so your automatic password is:",password_random)
```

This code requests the user to put a username that contains 8 characters and a password that contains 8 characters and at least one uppercase, one lowercase, one number and one symbol. Supposedly, when all these premises are satisfied, it should print the user name and the password. However, it doesn't.

Comment: that's... a lot of loops and if statements. I think the problem here is that the `if statements` don't automatically `break` all the nested `for loops`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as commented, you don't break out of any of the loops inside the "password check" - even if the `if`-condition is met. So each loop will iterate over all characters in password. Try putting some `print` statements in your code to see what's going on. In general, nesting so many loops and conditionals becomes almost impossible to read. Therefore I'd suggest to have a look at Python's [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Using these, you could e.g. refactor your password check like

```py
def check_pw(pw):
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    numbers = "0123456789"
    symbols = "¡!¿?<>$#@%&€*+-"
    contains_lower = any(l in pw for l in chars)
    contains_upper = any(l in pw for l in chars.upper())
    contains_nbr = any(l in pw for l in numbers)
    contains_sym = any(l in pw for l in symbols)
    return all((contains_lower, contains_upper, contains_nbr, contains_sym))
```

testing:

```
pws = ['asdfS7!l', 'asdf', 'TESTASEDFASDF']
for passphrase in pws:
    if len(passphrase) >= 8 and check_pw(passphrase):
        print(f"pw '{passphrase}' is ok.")
    else:
        print(f"pw '{passphrase}' is not ok.")
```

prints

```
pw 'asdfS7!l' is ok.
pw 'asdf' is not ok.
pw 'TESTASEDFASDF' is not ok.
```